# Search Soundcloud API with filters

Tags: ruby, soundcloud

According to the Soundcloud documentation (https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search,

> "Some resource types, such as sounds, can be filtered by fields like
>   license, duration or tag_list."

Is there some list in existence of what attributes can be filtered like this? For example, say I want to find artists with the name of 'billy' that have between 100 and 1000 followers. I would expect I could do (using the Ruby client)

`client.get('/users', q:'billy', followers_count: {from:1000, to:10000})`

But those followers_count limits are not respected in the results. Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you link says

For a complete list of search fields and filters, please see the API Reference for the resource type you'd like to search.

Comment: Hey @max pleaner, indeed it does. However there is no mention of search fields or filters in any resource type that I can find (for example, the case of users I mentioned in the question).

Comment: it doesn't look like you can do user queries like that; you'll have to get user ids some other way and then request data on a per-id bases. It doesn't look like the soundcloud website even offers that order-by-followers query

Comment: looks like you are right. Dear Soundcloud, please make the search API better. Would be useful/interesting to search users based on criteria and not just tracks.